# Is the list of packages available to install with `pkg` stored locally on FreeBSD? If so, how to update that cache?

Tags: freebsd, repository, cache, pkg

When looking for a package to install on FreeBSD 11.2, such as the *zsh* shell:

```
pkg search zsh
```

…is the searching done against a local cache of packages information, or run over the internet against some repository server?

If the search is local, how can I update that local cache to be sure it is complete and has the latest versions?

Comment: Well, [the manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg) says (my emphasis): "Search for the given pattern in the *remote* package repositories."

Comment: ... if that is a cache of a remote repository or not, I'm not sure, but it may well be (as there is also a `pkg update` command for updating the cache).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FreeBSD `pkg` command maintains an SQLite3 database in `/var/db/pkg/local.sqlite`.  This contains, amongst other things, downloaded package metadata that various `pkg` subcommands use, including `pkg search`.

`pkg update` is all that you need.  Note that an update is implicit in various `pkg` subcommands, and actually has to be turned off with the `-U` option.

Note that there are subsystems that might be present on derivatives such as TrueOS that regularly update these caches.